# Soft dewy glow lighting set up?

Tags: light, compositing-nodes

Does anyone have a way of creating this type of lighting in blender or is this something that's more easily achieved in photoshop?

The objects almost have this glowing aura and that's what I'm really looking to recreate !

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by mixing your "porcelain" material with an Emission Shader, driven by a Fresnel. Don't forget to enable bloom - you may want to increase the intensity as well (assuming you're using EEVEE).

[image: Glow1]

If you want to take it one step further and use the compositor, you can enhance the effect using a Glare node set to a high quality Fog Glow:

[image: Glow2]

The Fresnel trick may not work for the Vase, as it will cause the underside (shadowed areas) to be lit as well - unless you have the perfect IOR and camera angle, it ends up looking like a lamp. Instead, just use a very bright light, using the same bloom as before and the same compositor set up:

[image: Glow3]

Comment: Thank you! This really helps!

Answer (score 3):

To add to Christopher Bennett's answer, I think you have to look into the *Compositor* settings, for this kind of 70s look you can plug a *Filter > Glare > Streaks* into a *Blur* node. If you are in *Eevee*, enable the *Bloom* option:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip!